# How to suppress git message: fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree

Tags: git, version-control, zsh

When I in a git repo, and run `cd .git && git status` git will only show:

`fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`.

Is there a way to suppress this error message?

Another situation is after enable vcs in Zsh, `autoload -Uz vcs_info`, and if you in a `.git` directory, each command will get this error message.

Comment: @torek a little ocd ...

Comment: @torek There are perfectly valid reasons to be in the .git directory. That has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @jhpratt: maybe so, and it (zsh prompt magic complaining, that is) does seem like a bug. But if it's a big problem, either stay out of the `.git` directory or override the PS1 setting while in it (or, of course, fix the bug!).

Answer (score 0):

Found [git/git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) provided by git community could work with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to suppress this message when running `git status` manually because the command cannot work when you're not in a Git working tree.  `git status` shows things relative to the current working directory and that won't work if you're not in the working tree.

Note that zsh no longer has this problem if you upgrade to the latest version.  The built-in vcs-info code should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but seems lastest zsh version still have this problem on my computer. I'm on Manjaro Linux with zsh 5.8-1.